# Why Number('') and Number('null') retuns 0

Tags: javascript

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

> If the argument cannot be converted into a number, it returns `NaN`

Can some please explain why `Number('')` and `Number(null)` returns `0` because there are not valid numbers.
First I thought that this might be because they are falsy values. But then I found `Number(undefined)` doesnot returns `0`.

```js
console.log(Number(undefined)); //NaN
console.log(Number(null)); //0
console.log(Number('')); //0
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Convert_numeric_strings_and_null_to_numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Purely because the specification says so, [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor-number-value) and linking to [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tonumber). As far as I know, there's no deeper logic to it than that. The second link there shows what `Number` (when called as a function) does based on the type of the input:

> - Undefined => Return NaN.
> - Null => Return +0.
> - Boolean => If argument is true, return 1. If argument is false, return +0.
> - Number => Return argument (no conversion).
> - String => See grammar and conversion algorithm below.
> - Symbol => Throw a TypeError exception.
> - Object => Apply the following steps:
>
>   - Let primValue be ? ToPrimitive(argument, hint Number).
>   - Return ? ToNumber(primValue).

The "grammar and conversion algorithm below" says, amongst other things:

> The MV [mathematical value] of StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty] is 0.